# How can I use a an input command so as to define an integer and compare it to another integer?

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python and decided to make this program that does a Fibonacci Sequence so i could subsequently import it on a new program, however somethings wrong with it and I am not sure what it is.

```py
print(input('Please state the value of n: ' ))

a, b = 0, 1

print(a)

while b < n:

    print(b)

    a, b= b, a+b
```

I wanted to be able to import the input command but apparently somethings wrong with the code. Any help?

I tried adding `int(input('Please state the value of n'))` but it still does not work for some reason.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "import the input command"? And what exactly went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to assign the `input` to `n` and cast it to `integer` , that will fix your problem .

```
n = int(input('Please state the value of n: ' ))
```

Hope it helps <3

Comment: Thanks! I did exactly this and it worked! I must look very dumb in your eyes ,sorry I'll try harder next time :(

Comment: @nooneofinterestI you wouldn't learn it if u didn't ask , so no worries .

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to define 'n' as  variable.

```
n = (input('Please state the value of n: ' ))

a, b = 0, 1

print(a)

while b < n:

    print(b)

    a, b= b, a+b
```

Comment: I am so dumb, You are right I changed print(input("Please state the vlaue of n: ")) to n =int(input('please state the value of n: ')) and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: still need to wrap the input call with `int`. As it stands, `n` is a string.